# Nested resource, create action with two IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this link

```
link_to "Ban", group_banned_user_path(:group_id => object.group_id, :user_id => object.user.id), :method => :post
```

That triggers this controller action

```
def create
        @banned_user = BannedUser.new
        user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
        group.ban(user)
        redirect_to group
    end
```

Through this route

```
  resources :groups do
    member do
      post :join
      delete :leave
    end
    resources :banned_users, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

But I receive a "No route matches [POST] "/groups/4/banned_users/4", because there is no /:id option in the create action url. So my question is how can I access both the user, and group ID from the controller action, since passing them in as seperate arguments in the link_to doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you have the route `/groups/:id/banned_users/:banned_user_id`, it will basically require the following params to be present: `params[:id]` `params[:banned_user_id]`

--

You're sending this route:

```
group_banned_user_path(:group_id => object.group_id, :user_id => object.user.id)
```

This does not populate the `:id` field. You'll be best doing this:

```
group_banned_user_path(object.group_id, object.user.id)
```

--

**Update**

I think the answer to your question will be to manually declare your routes to accept the `:id` param:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :groups do
    post :join #-> you don't need member
    delete :leave
    resources :banned_users, only: [] do
       post ":id", action: "create" #-> groups/:id/banned_users/:id
       delete ":id", action: "destroy"
    end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the route I recommended above

Comment: Isn't there a more clean way to do it?

Comment: Probably! Why don't you try what I've recommended, and then we can refactor if it works for you?